# Why KeyRemap4MacBook mapping for home-end stopped working in browsers after migrating to Sierra from Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

This mapping is still working in MS Word and vi.
Also    Option-Tab stopped working for switching applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karabiner (the new name for this software) doesn't work on Sierra.  On the [developer's site](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) it states

> **macOS Sierra support status**
>
> Karabiner does not work on macOS Sierra at the moment.
>
> We are developing Karabiner-Elements which provides simple key modification for macOS Sierra at first.  (Karabiner-Elements works well on macOS Sierra. We are working on fixing several remaining issues.)
>
> We'll start updating for the full featured Karabiner for Sierra after Karabiner-Elements is completed.